# GIT : Maintains public forked project

Tags: git

We have a public repo, a fork of node. We added some patches. These patches works with the version of node we used.

We would like to update to the latest version of node. If we rebase, we will have clean patches (as we will have to fix them) on top of the latest version of node but we will break git pull on master...

If we merge, patches we did will no longer make sense as they will be broken with the latest version of node. We will have to commit fixes afters the merge.

What's the best way to handle that case ?

Comment: Merge, to keep your already published history, and then fix it afterwards. Just look at all the maintained forks of existing projects to see how they work.

Comment: So it means you have broken builds in the history ? (As long as you didn't fix bugs you introduced updating the fork)

Comment: Essentially, yes. Just fix them in the same push and you’re fine.